# Prove that $Q$ is a group under quaternion multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions

Consider the subset $Q$ of the quaternions defined by $$Q=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}.$$

Show that $Q$ is a group under quaternion multiplication.

---

I know to prove something's a group, you must show closure, associativity, identity, and inverses. So is the identity is $1$? Is each element is its own inverse? I'm not sure of the operation. I don't remember ever going over quaternions in class. Any guidance will be gratefully appreciated!

Comment: You have not had the multiplication of the quaternions defined?

Comment: No. This is a study guide for my exam and that's the prompt verbatim.

Comment: What about in the course material?

Comment: @allie and you tried to use the internet to look up what quaternions are and didn't find any answer? The [wiki tells you how to multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) them, for example.

Comment: Subgroups inherit associativity from the group so you never need to check that for a subgroup. But there will be loads of sources online that explain the quaternions as a group and you'll do this question fine once you have understood them.

Comment: @Edward Hart: any non-trivial ring isn’t a group under multiplication, whereas a concept of the multiplicative group of a ring is… a bit too abstract for newbs.